# iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Storyboards not being used

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

The 4.7 and 5.5 inch storyboards for my app are not being used at runtime. I've read several questions on here regarding support for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus and how we need to include the launch screen file in order for the system to know that we support the new screen sizes. However, after including the launch screen AND also including the LaunchImage files in xcassettes, my app will still pull from my 4.0 inch storyboard file and scale up those layouts. I'm also using Auto Layout and Size Classes. What am I doing wrong? Has anyone else encountered this issue and solved it? I've done as other question's answers have instructed on here, but I still cannot get my app to use the correct storyboards for the iPhone 6's. I've attached the code I use to select between storyboards for different devices.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard;
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    result = CGSizeMake(result.width *scale, result.height *scale);

    if (result.height == 960) {

        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mainViewController960 = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:mainViewController960];

    }else if (result.height == 1136) {

        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard4.0" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mainViewController1136 = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:mainViewController1136];

    }else if (result.height == 1334) {

        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard4.7" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mainViewController1334 = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:mainViewController1334];

    }else if (result.height == 2208) {

        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard55" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mainViewController2208 = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window setRootViewController:mainViewController2208];

    }
```

Comment: How are you selecting which storyboard to use?

Comment: have you single stepped through to see what is happening in your code?  I have to say that best practice is a single storyboard that adapts. This approach is fragile and can break if new devices are released.

Comment: "after including the launch screen AND also including the LaunchImage files in xcassettes" My guess is that you're doing that wrong. Please prove that you are actually _using_ the launch screen, not merely "including" it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't enough to "include" a launch screen. You must tell your app to *use* the launch screen, in the app target editor's General pane:

[image]

If your target editor doesn't look like that, you're not using the launch screen.

Also, note that sometimes the iPhone 6 or 6 Plus just *is* zoomed - that's a setting that can be made in the Settings app.

Comment: my target editor looks just like that, but the app is still using the iPhone 5 storyboard in zoomed view. I've also added all of the required launch images when bypassing the launch screen, and still the app uses the iPhone 5 storyboard.

Comment: How about if you take all that "load a different storyboard" code _out_? Are you zoomed then?